# Extract texture from 3D file

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, textures, extract

I have .ply file of 3D face. Its a combination of shape and texture. I want to extract the texture from this file and save this as .jpeg image as shown in picture. I want to do this in matlab please provide me some direction for this. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should read the .ply file specification

It will tell you that each ply file contains elements which themselves may have certain properties. For example colour values.

http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/

Now you have sets of colours and 3d coordinates. Now you have to apply some kind of projection to get from 3d to 2d.

Thanks to Mr bourke you won't have to walk too far to get info on that topic:
http://paulbourke.net/geometry/transformationprojection/

After you have created a 2d map of colours you may save it as a jpeg image.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, well I have able to read the ply file in matlab using read_ply method, it return  vertex and faces. Now, I want to project these to texture please guide me how do I proceed further in matlab to achieve this task. Thanks.

Comment: @Imi so you have 3d locations of colours, now you have to get that into 2d (into an image). read the article about projection methods, search the web for further ressources on 3d to 2d projections. pick what you need and implement it or find an implementation  from someone else.